# "By us" vs "by ourselves"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, reflexives

> You can check our privacy policy for more details on how and why data
>   is collected by our partners and **ourselves**.

or

> You can check our privacy policy for more details on how and why data
>   is collected by our partners and **us**.

"Us" implicitly refers to the publishers of an app. Which sentence is correct?

Comment: Or you could say "You can check our privacy policy for more details on how and why we and our partners collect data."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are absolutely correct, but here's a little more information to help you decide between the two in the future: sometimes *ourselves* can be used as an intensive form of we/us, to emphasize the point, as in the following variation of your sentence:

You can check our privacy policy for more details on how and why data is collected by we ourselves to ensure its safety.

In that sentence, *ourselves* emphasizes *we*. I realize that this is not how you used it in your sentence, however.

Comment: So English grammar is more permissive than I thought :). If both are correct, I will definitely go for the simpler and shorter language, which is "us".

Comment: That's what I would do, but I wasn't sure that it was appropriate to advise you to do that, since that is, strictly speaking, a matter of personal taste. But as long as we're going there, yeah, I agree with your choice; it's simpler, easier, and sounds more natural (to me).